# How to add conditional data-attribute tag to activate js code?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is there any way to apply condition for showing Javascript or Jquery code in HTML Template ?

Like, if there's any data-id attribute containing "no-copy" value inside body tag, some javascript code will be apply.

For Example, If theres any id with the name "no-copy", some javacript code block will be apply in the theme.

If I explain it with more easily, I have some js code for not copying text/content from my site. And also for disable ctrl+U and right button click. I want to apply them in my code, but conditionally. If users add data-id="no -copy" attributr inside body tag, my code (disable right button, select text etc.) will be apply or activate. Otherwise these code won't work.

Here's my simple approach:

```js
   let  = document.getElementById("divId").getAttribute("data-no-copy");
    function customAlert(message){
        $('[data-no-copy="active"]').html(message).fadeIn(300).delay(2000).fadeOut(400);
    };
    document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    customAlert('Right Click is Disabled');    
    }, false);
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
    #divId {
      max-width: 300px; 
      background-color: #333; 
      color: #fff; 
      font-size: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      border-radius: 2px; 
      padding: 10px; 
      position: fixed; 
      z-index: 1; 
      right: 5%; 
      bottom: 20px; 
      display: none;
    }
    </style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    
<body id="divId" data-no-copy="active"></body>
```

How I can activate this code only when users will add data-id="no -copy" attributr inside body tag. Not always activate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for the data-attribute value, like I did here on my example, and if the data-value match your string (ex., 'active') you can trigger the routines to avoid right click and copy, like this example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      #divId {
        max-width: 300px; 
        background-color: #333; 
        color: #fff; 
        font-size: 15px;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 2px; 
        padding: 10px; 
        position: fixed; 
        z-index: 1; 
        right: 5%; 
        bottom: 20px; 
      }
      </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    
  </head>
  <body id="divId" data-no-copy="active">

  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>


  <script>
      let  no_copy = document.getElementById("divId").getAttribute("data-no-copy");

      if(no_copy == 'active') {
        document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('Right Click is Disabled');    
        }, false);
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('body').bind('copy', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert('Copy is Disabled');  
          });
        });
      }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow.... It really sounds much better than previous one....❤️❤️❤️❤️

Comment: Show me the pointsss if you like  :D:D:D:D

Comment: But how can I also a condition, "inactive"..... I mean, if data-no-copy="inactive", code Should not work... Though removing data-no-copy attribute will not work. Yet, if there's any way to add this condition too...

Comment: Sure Mr. @Pedro.. But How can add inactive value conditions too.....?

Comment: If you have whatever instead of 'active' as your data-no-copy value, the script will not trigger, including data-no-copy="inactive", data-no-copy="", no data-no-copy attribute, etc etc etc